# VBA run code after user selects option from dynamic Form Control Combobox

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook where an unknown amount of data from text files can be imported (the user will import as many text files as they feel necessary). I am attaching an identifier (1, 2, 3, etc) each time a text file is imported to the workbook. On the "Information Sheet" I have a form control combobox where the user selects the "initial data set" aka (1, 2, 3, etc) by selecting the identifier value from the dropdown. What I want to happen is when the user selects a value to specify the initial data set, this data set will get highlighted in grey on the "Data Importation Sheet" aka the sheet where all the data gets imported to. I think my code is close but it isnt working.

Here is my code for the Combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Call Find_Initial_Data_Set
End Sub
```

And here is my code for highlighting the data in the "Data Importation Sheet" according to the value in cell E12 where my Combobox is located:

```
Sub Find_Initial_Data_Set()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim aCell1, aCell2, aCell3 As Range
    Dim NewRange As Range
    Dim A As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    Worksheets("Information Sheet").Activate

    If Range("E12").Value <> "" Then
        Set ws = Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet")
        A = Worksheets("Information Sheet").Range("E12").Value

        Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Activate

        With ws
            Set aCell = .Rows(1).Find(What:=A, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        End With

        LastRow = Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Row

        With ws
            Set aCell1 = aCell.Offset(0, -1)
            Set aCell2 = aCell.Offset(LastRow, 5)

            Debug.Print aCell1.FormulaR1C1
            Debug.Print aCell2.FormulaR1C1

            Set NewRange = .Range(aCell1.Address & ":" & aCell2.Address)

            Debug.Print NewRange.Address
        End With

        NewRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Here are some visuals of my excel book:
Data Importation Sheet where the data gets input (you cannot see the identifier in this pic but beneath the data I have a cell that says Identifier with the corresponding importation value beside it):
[image]

Information Sheet where the user selects the initial data set based on identifier:
[image]

And this is what I would like the Data Importation Sheet to look like after the user selects 1 (for example) for the initial data set:
[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need  to  change LastRow to the following  as  all you need is the row number:

```
LastRow = Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
```

Comment: Whoops, I must have deleted that line of code I will edit my code

Comment: Please delete this as an answer, should be a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

the code would be like this.

**sheet's code**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Call Find_Initial_Data_Set(ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

**module code**

```
Sub Find_Initial_Data_Set(A As String)

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, NewRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet")
    With Ws
        If A <> "" Then
            Set aCell = .Rows(1).Find(what:=A, after:=.Range("a1"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
            If aCell Is Nothing Then
            Else
                Set aCell = aCell.Offset(, -1)
                LastRow = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set NewRange = aCell.Resize(LastRow, 7)
                NewRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that cell E12 is not registering it contains a value when the user selects a value from the dropdown. Any tips?

Comment: @hdk857: in my code that is A varialble. A variable is combobox.text.

Comment: @hdk857:  other way,  ComboBox1.LinkedCell = "e12" ,   combobox  link with e12 cell.

Answer (score 0):

i rewrote your code somewhat

please single-step through code using F8 key

check if correct ranges are "selected" at "debug" lines

please update your post with findings

i suspect that the wrong cells are being referenced once the worksheet is partially populated

also, please refrain from using:   ( ... this means, anyone reading this)

```
    With ws
        Set aCell = .Rows(1).Find(What:=A, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
```

use this:

```
    Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=A, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

it is shorter and more readable

use "with" convention only if it really simplifies the code a lot

see the end of the code for info that may help you

```
Sub Find_Initial_Data_Set()

    Dim infoSht As Worksheet
    Dim dataImpSht As Worksheet

    Dim aCell As Range

'   Dim aCell1, aCell2 As Range    ' do not use ... aCell1 is declared as variant. not as range

    Dim aCell1 As Range, aCell2 As Range, aCell3 As Range
    Dim NewRange As Range
    Dim A As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    Set dataImpSht = Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet")
    Set infoSht = Worksheets("Information Sheet")

    A = infoSht.Range("E12").Value
    If A <> "" Then

        Set aCell = dataImpSht.Rows(1).Find(What:=A, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        dataImpSht.Activate                 ' debug   .Select command fails if sheet is not visible
        aCell.Select                        ' debug   (this should highlight "aCell")

        dataImpSht.Cells(dataImpSht.Rows.Count, "A").Select                        ' debug
        dataImpSht.Cells(dataImpSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select              ' debug
        dataImpSht.Cells(dataImpSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Select   ' debug
        dataImpSht.Cells(dataImpSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select    ' debug

        LastRow = dataImpSht.Cells(dataImpSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Row


        aCell.Select                         ' debug
        aCell.Offset(0, -1).Select           ' debug
        aCell.Offset(LastRow, 5).Select      ' debug

        Set aCell1 = aCell.Offset(0, -1)
        Set aCell2 = aCell.Offset(LastRow, 5)

        aCell1.Select                      ' debug
        aCell2.Select                      ' debug

        Debug.Print aCell1.FormulaR1C1
        Debug.Print aCell2.FormulaR1C1

        Set NewRange = dataImpSht.Range(aCell1.Address & ":" & aCell2.Address)

        NewRange.Select                      ' debug

        Debug.Print NewRange.Address

        NewRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 15

    End If


'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' check this out ... it may be what you need to use
        Dim aaa As Range

        Set aaa = dataImpSht.Cells(dataImpSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        aaa.Select
        aaa.Range("a1").Select   ' aaa can be thought off as the new top left corner
        aaa.Range("b2").Select   ' you can refer to cells in relation to aaa

        Set aaa = aaa.Offset(4)  ' and move position of aaa for each iteration
        aaa.Range("a1").Select
        aaa.Range("b2").Select
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that Cell E12 is not registering having a value in it from the drop down list. Any tips?